# Why does the pessimistic version constraint (~>) in Ruby not match?

Tags: ruby

I'm installing a gem and I received the following error:

```
ERROR:  While executing gem ... (Gem::ImpossibleDependenciesError)
    oauth2-0.9.4 requires multi_json (~> 1.3) but it conflicted:
    Activated multi_json-1.11.0 instead of (>= 0, ~> 0) via:
```

My understanding is that the pessimistic version constraint `~>` should match all except the last digit so that `1.3` should match `1.11` (and `1.11.0`?) but not `2.0`. What is this error message describing?

Update: It seems like `1.11` may be conflicting with a `~> 0` requirement somewhere else as mentioned in the error. Removing `~> 0` or changing it to `~> 1` works. As a follow on question, why doesn't `~> 0` match 1.x?

Comment: It does match, but you cut off the important line of the error, the next line - what else is requiring `multi_json` with what constraints?

Comment: It's a gem I'm building that had a `multi_json` constraint of `'~> 0','>= 0'`. I didn't realize that `~> 0` wouldn't match 1. If I remove the `~> 0` or change it to `~> 1` it will install. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Correct ~> 1.3 should match anything in the 1.x series.

`Gem::ImpossibleDependenciesError` means pretty much what it says. Some other dependency (whatever it prints after via: ) requires a different version to one that `~> 1.3` allows.